# Changing content of variables in toc (in ConTeXt): nested \def s

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, context, expansion

I try to define a "variable" for a category. Using it for the first time, the value should be reset until it is set again.

This is the desired output:

```
Fruit: Apricot
(also in category) Banana
(also in category) Cherry
Vegetable: Zucchini
(also in category) Yam
```

Look at the following LaTeX code, which does not yet work.

```
\documentclass{article}
% no packages allowed, I am actually using ConTeXt

\def\setcateg#1{\gdef\Categ{#1: }}
\def\resetcateg{\def\Categ{(also in category) }}
\def\insertcateg{\Categ\resetcateg}

\begin{document}
The simplified version works:

\setcateg{Fruit}
\insertcateg Apricot

\insertcateg Banana

\insertcateg Cherry

\setcateg{Vegetable}
\insertcateg Zucchini

\insertcateg Yam

But actually, I want to have this working in the toc.
\tableofcontents
\setcateg{Fruit}
\section[\insertcateg Apricot]{Apricot}
\section[\insertcateg Banana]{Banana}
\section[\insertcateg Cherry]{Cherry}
\setcateg{Vegetable}
\section[\insertcateg Zucchini]{Zucchini}
\section[\insertcateg Yam]{Yam}

\end{document}
```

This gives an \inaccessible error.

1. <s>How does it work in the text?</s> (Thanks to @Guho, the simple version works.) Why `\gdef`?
2. How does it work in the toc?
3. Why?

It might have something to do with expansion.

Please do not suggest special LaTeX packages, actually, I would like to use this in ConTeXt.

For the simplified text version, the following command definitions (using `\define` instead of `\def`) work in ConTeXt:

```
\define[1]\setcateg{\def\Categ{#1: }}
\define\resetcateg{\def\Categ{(also in category)}}
\define\insertcateg{\Categ\resetcateg}
```

Comment: I am confused about how you are expecting the TOC to work with this. Are you wanting to `\insertcateg` and have that be a section in the TOC? Should the `setcateg` argument be included in the TOC as well?

Comment: @Guho Your picture below is perfect. It is (due to other restrictions) admittedly not the perfect way to structure a toc. The point of the \insertcateg command is to be able to have "an arbitrary number of headlines in variable order" in this category without hardcoding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `#1` after `\setcateg`. Also, calling `\insertcateg` in the optional TOC heading forces some ugly `\def`'s to appear in the toc file which are the cause of your errors. What you want to appear in the TOC is the *result* and not the necessary code to achieve it. This can be accomplished by putting the `\section` command in the `\insertcateg` and passing the fruit or vegetable to it. This also has the advantage of needing the fruit or vegetable to be typed once. Below is the modified version which works (assuming this is what you are after):

```
\documentclass{article}
% no packages allowed, I am actually using ConTeXt

\def\setcateg#1{\def\Categ{#1:}}
\def\resetcateg{\def\Categ{(also in category)}}
\def\insertcateg#1{\section[\Categ\ #1]{#1}\resetcateg}

\begin{document}
% Actually, I want to have this working in the toc.
\tableofcontents
%\setcateg{Fruit}
%\section[\insertcateg Apricot]{Apricot}
%\section[\insertcateg Banana]{Banana}
%\section[\insertcateg Cherry]{Cherry}
%\setcateg{Vegetable}
%\section[\insertcateg Zucchini]{Zucchini}
%\section[\insertcateg Yam]{Yam}

The simplified version here does not work too.

\setcateg{Fruit}
\insertcateg{Apricot}

\insertcateg{Banana}

\insertcateg{Cherry}

\setcateg{Vegetable}
\insertcateg{Zucchini}

\insertcateg{Yam}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! I fixed the small error. You also switched one `\def` to `\gdef` ? But even with that, it does not yet work in the toc.

Comment: @One: The `gdef` was leftover from when I was diagnosing the problem before I recognized the parameter error. In this case `\def` is sufficient.

Comment: However, the number of errors for the full code is smaller using `\gdef`. But there are errors left: `\inaccessible`.